# Initialize array of 3-value structures using memset

Tags: c, arrays, opengl, memory, memset

How do I initialize array of structures with values?
So, I have structure color with rgb values.

```
struct color{
    GLfloat r;
    GLfloat g;
    GLfloat b;
}
```

and trying to initialize it with 1.0f.

```
color* cArray = (color*) malloc(w*h*sizeof(color));
memset(&cArray, 1.0, sizeof color);
```

But instead of correct work I get segmentation fault on cArray[0].
What do I miss?

Comment: `memset` used to set all values either to `0` or `-1`. Use a loop to set all values of an array to any values other than `0` or `-1`.

Comment: Note that `color` cannot be use as such in C (that would be C++). `struct` has its own namespace, so you have to either `typedef` the struct or use `struct color` in the definition of the pointer.

Answer (score 3):

Note: Do not cast `void *` (result of `malloc()`) to other pointers and **always check the result of `malloc()`& friends**.

Memset takes an unsigned char (most likely 8 bits) and treats the area passed as an array of char. It has no idea of structs, arrays etc. Just of a 1-dimensional array of char. (as @chqrlie noted, `memset()` actually takes an `int`; this is, however, internally converted to `unsigned char`).

The segfault is because you pass the address of `cArray` which is a pointer to the actual array, not its value which would be the array itself.

For float, memset() most likely only makes sense setting it to all-`0`:

```
memset(cArray, 0, sizeof(struct color) * w * h);
```

Note: memset has no idea on data types. It just takes a pointer to a block of memory and a count and stores the value to that area. It is **your** responsibility all arguments are valid!

Note that writing the memory area with `0` is actually float zero (`0.0`, actually `+0.0`), as that has all bits cleared. That was a briliant intention by the guys who dsigned the encoding for floats.

As you allocate right before, you can combine this using `calloc()`. That will allocate and clear the memory area of the array. However, if you intend to set all values explicitly anyway, you better stick with `malloc()`.

If you want to set other float values, you have to write your own loop. However, you can threat the array as 1-dimensional for that.

```
for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < w * h ; i++ )
    cArray[i] = (struct color){ .r = 1.0, .g = 1.0, .b = 1.0 };
```

That uses a *compound literal*. Alternatively you can also set the fields seperately.

If you are upt for speed, the compount-literal approach might be the fastest. This way ,the compiler might very well load al values into three registers and store them directly into memory using store-multiple. However it might do, I would bet the compiler will recognize that pattern and optimize as hell, as it is commonly used for very large loops.

Comment: Wow, these moving votation div's are funny, and they don't move for own posts!

Comment: @iharob: I would probably "wow", too, if I would understand what you mean.

Comment: @chqrlie: No, I did not (*whistle*:-)

Comment: The answer score is moving with the answer body, it wasn't before.

Comment: Ok, well, I have problems with my keyboard. the letters and not always where I expect them to be. Lucky, my compiler has all warnings on :-)

Comment: @chqrlie: Well.. it requires an int argument that is internally converted to an unsigned char. As a char is never larger than int and anything else is practically useless, it is just the same. Background is that old K&R C did not allow `char` arguments. All were converted to int. But, ok, I'll edit that, too.

Comment: @chqrlie: As the OP apparently wanted to set all values to `1.0`, `calloc()` would not make much sense. I treat that `memset()` just as an anecdote. But, ok, I'll edit (again) ... anything else (burger, fries, coke, döner? ;-))

Comment: @chqrlie: Pew, done. If there is anything else now, you're welcome to edit yourself:-)

Comment: @user3629249: Where do I state otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `memset()` to set `float` values.

The `memset()` function is used for bytes, so using it for `float`s is not allowed, you need to explicitly initialize each member

This is `memset()`'s signature

```
void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);
```

although it expects `int`<sup>1</sup> for it's second parameter, the standard says

> **7.24.6 Miscellaneous functions**
>
> **7.24.6.1 The `memset` function**
>
> 2. The `memset` function copies the value of `c` **(converted to an `unsigned char`)** into each of the first `n` **characters** of the object pointed to by `s`.

"*converted to an `unsigned char`*" so it sets bytes.

Also take in consideration the following:

1. You [don't need to cast the return value of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1983495), and it's better if you don't do it.
2. Always check that `malloc()` returned non-`NULL`, specially when allocating a lot of memory.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>As you can see you can't pass float.</sub>

Comment: Ok, i'll notice.
So what can I use to set this array?
I has more then 50000 vertices in vertex array, so for-loop is too expensive for per-frame updating

Comment: `memset()` does loop after all, so I don't think there would be another way.

Comment: @mersinvald: The `for` loop can be optimized to the max by the compiler. See this page: http://gcc.godbolt.org/# .  You can also keep a copy of a pre-initialized array and use `memcpy` to initialize the array.

Comment: @chqrlie yes, one like the one in @[Olaf](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30676053/1983495)'s answer.

Comment: @iharob: not exactly, the OP could keep a full initialized frame and use `memcpy(cArray, cStaticFrame, w * h * sizeof(color));` to initialize it.  It might be more or less efficient depending on his configuration.  Benchmarking is required.

Comment: Yes initialized statically with `{ .r = 1.0, .g = 1.0, .b = 1.0 }`.

Comment: @iharob: No, initialized with a loop because `w` and `h` are variables.

Comment: @chqrlie: `memcpy()` will likely be slower than explicit initializing and use up cache.

Comment: It's interesting that someone would downvote this answer, I wish they leave a comment, because I can't really see anything wrong with it, but it seems that lately someone is just downvoting **my** posts, which is a stupid thing. I have had more than 100 rep points reverse because of serial downvoting.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems with your code:

You allocate a matrix `w` x `h` of `color` structures:

```
color *cArray = (color*) malloc(w * h * sizeof(color));
```

The cast is not necessary in C, but opinions differ about the recommended alternatives.  A safer version would be:

```
color *cArray = malloc(w * h * sizeof(*cArray));
```

More importantly, our call to `memset` is incorrect in multiple ways:

```
memset(&cArray, 1.0, sizeof color);
```

1. You pass the address of the pointer instead of the value of the pointer `cArray`.
2. You only pass the size of a single `color` structure.  This size exceeds the size of the pointer, hence the crash.  If you intended to set the whole array you should have store the size into a temporary variable.
3. You pass a `double` instead of an int as the value to set.  You cannot initialize an array of  `double` values with `memset`: this function initializes a block of memory by setting all bytes to the same value.  Passing `0` would initialize `double` values correctly if your system uses IEEE-754 representation for floating point values, otherwise it might invoke undefined behaviour.

You must initialize the matrix with a loop:

```
for (size_t i = 0, n = w * h; i < n; i++) {
    cArray[i].r = cArray[i].g = cArray[i].b = 1.0;
}
```

This loop can be optimized by modern compilers.  I suggest you play with this very interesting tool: http://gcc.godbolt.org/# .

You can also keep a copy of a pre-initialized array and use `memcpy` to initialize the allocated array.

Answer (score -2):

First, colors are (in your case) 3 bytes, not 3 floats.

then this code:

```
struct color{
    GLfloat r;
    GLfloat g;
    GLfloat b;
}

and trying to initialize it with 1.0f.

color* cArray = (color*) malloc(w*h*sizeof(color));
memset(&cArray, 1.0, sizeof color);
```

will cause a compiler to raise several warnings:

due to the compiler will not knowing what a 'color' is due to:

```
syntax errors in the struct definition
and references to the struct are missing the 'struct' modifier.
```

when calling malloc() (and family of functions) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

In C, do not cast the returned value from malloc() (and family of functions)

notice that a struct definition ends with a ';'

suggest using:

```
struct color
{
    char r;
    char g;
    char b;
};

struct color* cArray = NULL;
if( NULL == (cArray =malloc(w*h*sizeof(struct color))))
{ // then malloc failed
    perror( "malloc for struct color array failed" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE )
}

// implied else, malloc successful

memset(&cArray, 1, w*h*(sizeof (struct color) );
```

Comment: OpenGL wiki states [different](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Scalars). Where did you get the idea of GL**float** being a byte?

Comment: Indeed `GLfloat` seems to be a 32 bit IEEE-754 floating point value aka `float`